# Phonegap 3.5 splashscreen can't display

Tags: cordova

I am a newbie on Phonegap development. I am trying to add a splashscreen to my app, but I can't.Here is my code in config.xml (in root folder):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.unitech.pushplugindemo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>PushPluginDemo</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.pushplugin" />
    <icon src="www/img/icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
        <splash src="www/img/screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    </platform>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
</widget>
```

I have already added the plugin: org.apache.cordova.splashscreen. And I am testing on Android Emulator.  It didn't show anything. I checked the logcat but it show no errors. How can I do now? Please, help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add these lines to `config.xml` file in `\platforms\android\res\xml` and for instance if you have ios then same for `config.xml` in `\platforms\ios\res\xml`

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

here value="screen" is because you splashscreen name will be `screen.png` but if you have somthing else like `myscreen.png` then value will be `value="myscreen"`. you can change delay time by increasing `value="3000"` to your requirement for instance 5 sec `value="5000"`

Comment: So, if I want to add a splash screen to IOS. Do I have to change some codes in config.xml (in IOS platform) too? Because I read this : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html, so I think "name="android"" show Phonegap know that this for Android platforms and we don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your helping. BTW, If I build an app which includes some features such as: webview, push notification,.. for both Android and IOS platform, I have to code 2 sources code. In some case, we have to config and change the content in each platforms. Is that right? :)

Comment: @anle you have to code once and configurations are different just. that are also not too much :)

Comment: But I add those code in \platforms\android\res\xml: <preference name="SplashScreen" value="www/img/screen.png" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />. It does't work too. Do I have to copy the picture to \res\drawable ? I am sorry because I have too much problems to solve. Hope you can help.

Comment: no you dont have to give whole path just the name of picture with out extension like "screen" from screen.png